# Change reference line in a git hunk?

Tags: git

Is it possible in Git to control which lines that should be considered to have been added? Ran into this at work and while not a problem in it self, it is more of an eyesore in the commit diff. See some additional comments in the code blocks.

I have tried `git add -p` to manually edit the hunk, but can't get it to work. It accepts the hunk, but reverts to the original one. Tried changing the line ranges in the diff.

Also tried Git Gui, but run into:

> Failed to stage the selected line

*Using Git v.2.11.0.*

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    android:text="@string/foo" />

<RadioButton <!-- This radio button was pasted from above... -->
    android:id="@+id/foo2"
    android:text="@string/foo2" />

<RadioButton <!-- ...in the same spot that this one used to live -->
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:text="@string/bar" />
```

And this is the diff

```
--- a/layout.xml
+++ b/layout.xml
@@ -3,5 +3,9 @@
        android:text="@string/foo" />

 <RadioButton <!-- Technically this was the line I did add -->
+       android:id="@+id/foo2"
+       android:text="@string/foo2" />
+
+<RadioButton <!-- And not this one -->
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:text="@string/bar" />
```

I would like it to look like this

```
+<RadioButton
+       android:id="@+id/foo2"
+       android:text="@string/foo2" />
+
 <RadioButton
```

Could this be changed or should I just learn to live with it? :) Thanks!

Comment: You may try with `git diff --patience`, but since git doesn't care about language semantics, you won't always have the "best" diff.

Comment: Thanks never heard of it before, but `git diff --patience` reports the same diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't *store* diffs, it stores complete files.  It *generates* diffs on the fly, at the time you ask for them.  That includes the `git add -p` step (i.e., this generates a new diff), and each run of `git show`, `git log -p`, and so on.

Since version 2.9.0, Git's diff has an experimental `--compaction-heuristic` option, which will shift the diff up to a blank line if possible.  Note that it requires an actual blank line above the patch, and there is one in your example.  If your Git version is 2.9.1 or higher, `git add -p` will also honor your configured `diff.compactionHeuristic` setting.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) (search for `compactionHeuristic`).

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer, made the diff concept clearer to me! `--compaction-heuristic` does what I want :)